# How to horizontally center Twitter Bootstrap grid elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website built entirely on Twitter Bootstrap 3. I am using the grid system all over the site but I have a specific use case on one page. It will display a grid of dynamically generated thumbnails but it's supposed to start populating them from the center out. Twitter Bootstrap grid elements align themselves from left to right by default (using float: left). I've tried a few things but so far haven't been able to come up with a way to change that behavior with just html and css. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here's a fiddle of how I DON'T want it to look: http://jsfiddle.net/9hLS6/

Note how the thumbnails align themselves to the left. Instead, I want them to "start" in the center and then each following one should place itself to right of the previous one so that they are always centered (adjusting for the default offset in a 6 column layout). Here's how I want the elements to flow illustrated in an awesome graphic:

```
|       O          |// row with one thumb
|       O  O       |// row with 2 thumbs
|    O  O  O       |// ...
|    O  O  O  O    |
| O  O  O  O  O    |
| O  O  O  O  O  O |
```

Comment: can you provide with your `html` `css` here or fiddle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - so keep in mind that I don't know exactly how you're pulling these dynamic elements. If I were trying to achieve these effect, I'd use a relatively straight forward PHP method.

**Determine the number or rows & the remainder**

```
// For the sake of the example lets say its 16
$elements = 16;

// Consider your 6 column layout
$eachrow = 6;

// Determine number of rows & remainder
$rows = $elements / $eachrow;
$lastrow = $elements % $eachrow;

// In case you don't have a multiplier of 6
  if ($lastrow > 0) { 
    $rows = $rows+1; 
  }
```

**Use the correct offset depending on the remainder**

```
// The last row's classes are dependent on number of elements.

if ($remainder == 1) {
  $remclass1 = ".col-md-1 .col-md-offset-2";
}

if ($remainder == 2) {
  $remclass1 = ".col-md-1 .col-md-offset-2";
  $remclass2 = ".col-md-1";
}

if ($remainder == 3) {
  $remclass1 = ".col-md-1 .col-md-offset-1";
  $remclass2 = ".col-md-1";
  $remclass3 = ".col-md-1";
}

if ($remainder == 4) {
  $remclass1 = ".col-md-1 .col-md-offset-1";
  $remclass2 = ".col-md-1";
  $remclass3 = ".col-md-1";
  $remclass4 = ".col-md-1";
}

if ($remainder == 5) {
  $remclass1 = ".col-md-1";
  $remclass2 = ".col-md-1";
  $remclass3 = ".col-md-1";
  $remclass4 = ".col-md-1";
  $remclass4 = ".col-md-1";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all. I know how to center elements. That's trivial. I am specifically trying to populate dynamic elements from the center out, meaning there could be any number of elements and each one should be added to the center (instead of to the left), pushing the previous one to the left until the row is fully populated with 6 elements and the next one will start to be populated.

Comment: If you had a jsfiddle we can look at, maybe what you're looking for would be clearer. What are you trying to work around? The fact that TB3's grid elements have a float:left characteristic that would order your thumbnails left to right? Or are you only looking to ensure that there is equal spacing on either side of your set of thumbnails, regardless of the number of thumbnails called?

Comment: I created a fiddle and elaborated on the question.

Comment: Last question for you, how are you dynamically adding these thumbnails? Are you using php? Or is there another language that you're relying on?

Comment: The backend is PHP but the elements are added to the view using javascript.

Comment: Thank you. It's not exactly what I was looking for as I was hoping to find a way to do this without any kind of scripting just with html/css/bootstrap but I'll leave it here for reference.